# How to copy column from one table to another which can be joined by ID?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
UPDATE    s  
SET s.TECH_NAME = r1.TECH_NAME 
FROM **ERRMSG** s INNER JOIN **RAWDATA** r1 on 
s.id = r1.id;
```

I want to update tech_name in table **ERRMSG** from table **RAWDATA**.Joining condition is ID.Whats wrong in the above query.Im getting the following error

```
Error at Command Line : 62 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the MERGE statement documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

This is more in the spirit of what you were trying to do, it avoids correlated subqueries, and it gives you more flexibility.

```
merge into errmsg s
   using rawdata r1
   on (s.id = r1.id)
when matched then update set s.tech_name = r1.tech_name
```

If needed, you can use the other capabilities of MERGE as well; for example, when NOT matched, the id in the errmsg table does not have a corresponding id in the rawdata table. Would you like to take an action in that case as well? You could, for example, set the tech_name to NULL or some default value or delete the row altogether - you can do all these things in **one** MERGE statement. See the documentation I provided.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is that you are using syntax that Oracle does not support.  Use a correlated subquery instead:

```
UPDATE errmsg s  
    SET s.TECH_NAME = (SELECT r1.TECH_NAME FROM rawdata r1 WHERE s.id = r1.id)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rawdata r1 WHERE s.id = r1.id)
```

Comment: Is your exists query more efficient than this ? `UPDATE    s  
SET s.TECH_NAME = (select r1.TECH_NAME 
FROM RAWDATA r1 where s.id = r1.id)`

Comment: @cableload . . . Possibly.  It is more accurate, in the sense that it does not set `TECH_NAME` to `NULL` when there is no match.